# template class that derives from same template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have an equivalent to following code:

```
struct Empty {
  static constexpr int id = 0;
};

template <typename Self, typename Base = Empty> struct Compound : public Base
{
  int get_id() const
  {
    return Self::id;
  }
};

struct A : Compound<A>
{
  static constexpr int id = 0xa;
};

struct B : Compound<B, A>
{
  static constexpr int id = 0xb;
};

template <typename T, typename Base> int get_id(const Compound<T, Base> &c)
{
  return c.get_id();
}


int test_a()
{
  A var;
  return get_id(var);
}

int test_b()
{
  B var;
  return get_id(var);
}
```

test_b doesn't compile with following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'get_id(B&)'
   return get_id(var);
                    ^
note: candidate: template<class T, class Base> int get_id(const Compound<T, Base>&)
 template <typename T, typename Base> int get_id(const Compound<T, Base> &c)
                                          ^
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'const Compound<T, Base>' is an ambiguous base class of 'B'
   return get_id(var);
```

I understand why that is. B is derived and is convertible to both `Compound<B, A>` and `Compound<A, Empty>`

I'm wondering if it is possible to change (within context of C++14) Compound template and get_id() function such that it would return 0xa for A and 0xb for B and would work for arbitrarily long chains of inheritance.

I know that this can be easily solved with virtual function that is overridden in A and B, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Everywhere these types are used they are known and fixed at compile time so there shouldn't be a need to incur run-time overhead.

Comment: "B is convertible to both `Compound<B,A>` and `Compound<A,Empty>`" - that's what "ambiguous base class" means.

Comment: Can't you have `template<typename Self, typename ... Ts>
struct Compound: public Ts... {/*...*/};` ?

Comment: There is functionality in Compound that is needed in both A and B. Here is is represented in simplified form as get_it() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep it simple:

```
template <class T>
auto get_id(T const& c) -> decltype(c.get_id())
{
    return c.get_id();
}
```

You don't *need* `c` to be some `Compound`, you really just want it to have a `get_id()` member function.

Comment: Ended up doing something very similar template <typename T> typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Empty, T>::value, int>::type get_id(const T &c) { return c.get_id(); }

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your post why need to go the route of `Compound` in `get_id`. You can simply use:

```
template <typename T> int get_id(T const& c)
{
  return T::id;
}
```